# what happens when a SharePoint online list/library exceed 30 million items/documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration

I am reading the SharePoint online limitations @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits but i am not sure what will happen when a SharePoint online list/library exceed 30 million items/documents? will it raise a warning that the list/library no more accept new items/lists or it will stop opening even in read only view?

Comment: Check if this helps (related to site limits): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/404929/what-happens-if-you-exceed-your-sharepoint-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

When a list, library, or folder contains more than 100,000 items, you can't break permissions inheritance on the list, library, or folder.

And the speed will be significantly reduced. When you do some operations in the document library, you may receive warings.